# WiX installer keeping copies of files of the different installation versions

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am installing two different versions of a project in which files have the same names and same installation location. How can I keep both the files?

Let's say I want to keep a copy of files of my version 1.0.0 and then also want to keep the copy of files of version 1.0.1. At the moment, I can see different installation versions in the control panel, but the files have only one copy.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this only when you are installing assemblies into GAC. You can’t have same filename in same folder. The newer version files will overwrite the older version files. 
If you want to keep both versions, use version number in installation location.

```
e.g.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Samples installer\1.0.0
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Samples installer\1.0.1
```

Comment: He'll probably also want to change the ProductName, ProductVersion, ProductCode and UpgradeCode properties from release to release.